# Service timed out when accessing Firebase database within Alexa

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to read a Object from database in Firebase. I found [an example in GitHub using firebase-admin](https://github.com/MGItkin/FreeRTOS-distributed-monitoring). I tried to do it similar fashion. When i try to test it on the service simulator in developer console, it fails to access the data from Firebase, and it terminates by mentioning that the service has expired. I'm not sure if I'm missing any step.

Below are things which i did to test it:

> I disabled the auth in firebase Console and made it to be Public.
>   I also tried it with Firebase module, and Firebase-admin module, its the same case with both options. 
>   Increased the timeout in AWS console to 2 minutes, but didn't help.

I also looked at other SO questions, but it didn't help to solve this issue.

Below is my code from index.js:

```
    'use strict';
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
// Initialize fireBase with a service account, granting admin privileges
var firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert("firebase-auth.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://alexa-595c9.firebaseio.com/"
});

var APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.13638113-6557-4cff-84d2-6d46e7f7539e';

var dataRef = firebaseAdmin.database().ref("Data");

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};


var handlers = {

    //Use LaunchRequest, instead of NewSession if you want to use the one-shot model
    // Alexa, ask [my-skill-invocation-name] to (do something)...
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.attributes['speechOutput'] = this.t("WELCOME_MESSAGE", this.t("SKILL_NAME"));
        // If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something that is not
        // understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
        this.attributes['repromptSpeech'] = this.t("WELCOME_REPROMT");
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes['speechOutput'], this.attributes['repromptSpeech'])
    },
    'QueryIntent': function () {

        var speechOutput
        var itemSlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.Item;
        var itemName; // name of dataRequested
        if (itemSlot && itemSlot.value) {
            itemName = itemSlot.value.toLowerCase();
        }
        // Call to FireBase for data object
        dataRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            var firebaseData = snapshot.val();
            console.log('Connection success');
            console.log('snapshot:',snapshot,'firebasedata:',firebaseData);
                        var parsedItemName = parseSimilar(itemName);

             switch(parsedItemName){
                case "temperature":
                    speechOutput = "The board's " + itemName + " sensor reads: " + firebaseData.temp + " degrees fahrenheit.";
                    break;
                     case "light":
                    speechOutput = "The board's " + itemName + " sensor reads: " + firebaseData.light + " lumens.";
                    break;
                case "memory":
                    speechOutput = "The board is using " + firebaseData.mem.globalUsed + firebaseData.mem.mallocUsed + " out of " + firebaseData.mem.systemAvail + " total memory blocks. Malloc is using " + firebaseData.mem.mallocUsed + " blocks, global space is using " + firebaseData.mem.globalUsed + " blocks and there are " + firebaseData.mem.mallocUsed + " availble malloc blocks.";
                    break;
                case "button":
                    speechOutput = "The button press status is as follows: Button 1: " + firebaseData.sw[0] + ", Button 2: " + firebaseData.sw[1] + ", Button 3: " + firebaseData.sw[2] + ", and Button 4: " + firebaseData.sw[3] + ". ";
                    break;
                case "task":
                    speechOutput = "The top three tasks using the most CPU are as follows: " + firebaseData.task[0].name + ". with " + firebaseData.task[0].percent + " percent... " + firebaseData.task[1].name + ". with " + firebaseData.task[1].percent + " percent... and " + firebaseData.task[2].name + ". with " + firebaseData.task[2].percent + " percent. ";
                    break;
                case "accelerometer":
                        speechOutput = "The accelerometer reads: X: " + firebaseData.x + ". Y: " + firebaseData.y + ". and, Z: " + firebaseData.z + ". ";
                        break;
                case "last update time":
                        speechOutput = "The last update was recieved on <say-as interpret-as=\"date\">" + firebaseData.date + "</say-as> at " + "<say-as interpret-as=\"time\">"+ firebaseData.time.substring(0,5) + "</say-as> . ";
                    break;

                default:
                    speechOutput = null;
                    break;
            }
            if (speechOutput !== null) {
                this.attributes['speechOutput'] = speechOutput;
                this.attributes['repromptSpeech'] = this.t("RECIPE_REPEAT_MESSAGE");
                this.emit(':askWithCard', this.attributes['speechOutput'], this.attributes['repromptSpeech'], cardTitle, speechOutput);
            } else {
                var speechOutput = this.t("RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE");
                var repromptSpeech = this.t("RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_REPROMPT");
                if (itemName) {
                    speechOutput += this.t("RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_WITH_ITEM_NAME", itemName);
                } else {
                    speechOutput += this.t("RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_WITHOUT_ITEM_NAME");
                }
                speechOutput += repromptSpeech;

                this.attributes['speechOutput'] = speechOutput;
                this.attributes['repromptSpeech'] = repromptSpeech;

                this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },

    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        this.attributes['speechOutput'] = this.t("HELP_MESSAGE");
        this.attributes['repromptSpeech'] = this.t("HELP_REPROMT");
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes['speechOutput'], this.attributes['repromptSpeech'])
    },
    'AMAZON.RepeatIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes['speechOutput'], this.attributes['repromptSpeech'])
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.emit('SessionEndedRequest');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.emit('SessionEndedRequest');
    },
    'SessionEndedRequest':function () {
        this.emit(':tell', this.t("STOP_MESSAGE", this.t("SKILL_NAME")));
    }
};

var languageStrings = {
    "en-US": {
        "translation": {
            "SKILL_NAME" : "MicroWatch",
            "WELCOME_MESSAGE": "Welcome to %s. You can request SJOne board info by saying things like, 'what is the current temperature', or 'what is the current light value'... Now, what can I help you with?",
            "WELCOME_REPROMT": "For a list of accepted commands, just say 'help'.",
            "DISPLAY_CARD_TITLE": "%s  - Value for %s.",
            "HELP_MESSAGE": "You can say things like, 'what is the current temperature'... Or you can invoke the skill directly by saying 'Ask MicroWatch for the current temperature'... Now, what can I help you with?",
            "HELP_REPROMT": "You can say things like, 'what is the current temperature', or you can say exit... Now, what can I help you with?",
            "STOP_MESSAGE": "Thanks for using %s, Goodbye!",
            "RECIPE_REPEAT_MESSAGE": "Try saying repeat.",
            "RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE": "I'm sorry, I currently can't monitor ",
            "RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_WITH_ITEM_NAME": "the %s. ",
            "RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_WITHOUT_ITEM_NAME": "that parameter. ",
            "RECIPE_NOT_FOUND_REPROMPT": "What else can I help with?"
        }
    }
};

function parseSimilar(item){
    switch(item){
        case "task usage":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "cpu usage":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "cpu":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "tasks":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "top tasks":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "top three tasks":
            item = "task";
            break;
        case "last update":
            item = "last update time";
            break;
        case "accel":
            item = "accelerometer";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return item
}
```

Please let me know if anyone tried it. Looking forward to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Is this a AWS lambda? Are you sure you are using the lambda wrapper callback correctly? Post the whole lambda source. You will get a timeout if the node event loop is stuck waiting.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you call dataRef.once()?  You're getting the val of the snapshot, and then what?  It doesn't look like you posted your whole function here.

Comment: Hi @Mike, yes its a lamba function.I have updated the full code.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @DougStevenson, The intention for this function is to get a single snapshot values from database and ALEXA reads the parameters out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are ever telling the runtime you are done. You have to do one of the following:

- call the callback function
- call the context.done function
- call the context.succeed function
- call the context.fail function

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

You want to do one of these AFTER your code is really done, not at the bottom of your top handler function. Since you are using async calls, you need to call it at the end of the last one to execute.

Don't forget error cases also, you should be calling context.fail(someErr) or callback(someErr) anywhere you stop running because of an error which often means adding catch() handlers.

Comment: Hi @Mike, Thanks for the prompt response. I tried to add the callback function in case of success and a callback in case if the dataref.once method returns error to notify this information to the caller. But unfortunately, it didn't work.